# CSRF markup fix

Tags: asp.net, webforms, csrf

I have a fortify result saying that the following line needs a secret to prevent CSRF

```
<form id ="form1test1" runat="server">
```

I have a random GUID being generated on Page Load, I want to compare it, when the form posts.

I have seen in classic asp putting the token in the action as a query string

I am trying:

```
<form "form1test1" runat="server" 
      action='<%# string.Concat(Eval("login.aspx/?Token="),"",Eval(Session["Token"].ToString()))%> '> >
```

Best I get is a print out of the text but not the values, not doing this in the code behind does not fix the finding in fortify
trying for something like

```
<form "form1test1" runat="server" action="login.aspx/?Token=12345DEF">
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to prevent CSRF attacks (it's working on my projects), is to implement it in your master pages, like this:

Add new Class that will handle the CSRF Validations for you:

```
public class CsrfHandler
{
    public static void Validate(Page page, HiddenField forgeryToken)
    {
        if (!page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Guid antiforgeryToken = Guid.NewGuid();
            page.Session["AntiforgeryToken"] = antiforgeryToken;
            antiforgery.Value = antiforgeryToken.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Guid stored = (Guid)page.Session["AntiforgeryToken"];
            Guid sent = new Guid(antiforgery.Value);
            if (sent != stored)
            {
                // you can throw an exception, in my case I'm just logging the user out
                page.Session.Abandon();
                page.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then implement this in your master pages:

MyMasterPage.Master.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CsrfHandler.Validate(this.Page, forgeryToken);
    ...
}
```

MyMaster.Master:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="forgeryToken" runat="server"/>
    ...
</form>
```

Hope you'll find this useful.

Comment: I tried something along the lines for that, and fortify still shows it wanting the secret on the line with the <form> tag, my goal is to not just fix it, I have a fix for it, i want fortify to no longer show.